# RaisedButton is debricated what is the alternative?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-upgrade

Just now I upgraded to Flutter 3.3.0, and after that this error is showing up:

> The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the type '_PickerFieldState'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.

Answer (score 3):

You can check [breaking-changes/buttons#context](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#context)
[image]

Instead of FlatButton, we need to use `TextButton`

To have similar ui we can use this style

```dart
final ButtonStyle flatButtonStyle = TextButton.styleFrom(
  primary: Colors.black87,
  minimumSize: Size(88, 36),
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)),
  ),
);

TextButton(
  style: flatButtonStyle,
  onPressed: () { },
  child: Text('Looks like a FlatButton'),
)
```

Ref and find more about [restoring the original button visuals](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#restoring-the-original-button-visuals)

Answer (score 1):

FlatButton is deprecated, use TextButton instead. Like this:

```
TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('Tap')),
```

Comment: can u help to improv the qst bro

Answer (score 0):

Check out this image for debricated widgets

[image: Check out this image for debricated widgets]